# Hazelcast Client Memory Leak

Tags: memory, client, hazelcast

We have Spring Boot 2.0.4 application. We use distributed Hazelcast 3.11 cache. In our application we configured HazelcastClient which connects to a Hazelcast server in Docker container.

In cache we store different "persons" in one map and the same "persons" but as a list in another (~900 persons in one list by one key; these persons in both maps are not the same for 100%, they both describe the person in real life but the last one in the list have less properties.). All the maps are of BINARY type.

When we made stress tests to get person by random id from the cache (1st map), everything went excellent. 5000 concurrent requests didn't influence our application HEAP at all, 10000 - slightly. In JSON format one person details has the size of 10kB.

When we made stress tests to get the list of persons from the cache (2nd map) we faced problems with the HEAP of our application where the client is configured. We made just 500 concurrent requests and the HEAP grew to 4Gb size! In JSON format the list has the size of 800kB. It is stored in the 2nd map and was requested by the same key 500 times.

Does anybody know what is going on?

[DTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjqDP.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5a0x.png)

[Method of a Facade which is retrieved from the Controller, and where caching takes place via @Cacheable annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nhu3.png)

[HazelcastInstance configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3UWC.png)

[hazelcast.xml configuration for the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RfuN.png)

[500 concurrent requests (3 times in a row)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTizk.png)

[Heap, Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAzj.png)

UPDATED:

I made 500 concurrent requests sequentially 23 times. Below we can see the final minutes of the test.

[Telemetries Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0NbP.png)

Comment: It looks like your concurrent requests for the second map returned high amount of data since each request returns the whole persons list. To understand if you are facing a memory leak or not, you need to continue your stress test for a while with the same number of concurrent requests. If you end up with an `OutOfMemoryError`, than there might be a memory leak somewhere. Can you please perform your stress test as I described and share the result?

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: AlparslanAvci, I've just updated my question with the screenshot of the test

Comment: @AlparslanAvci, As you see, OOME didn't happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: [Class instances just after the test](https://i.imgur.com/q630TXJ.png)

Comment: @AlparslanAvci, We have tested out application on Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. The application behaves differently with 500 concurrent requests. On Ubuntu it takes up to 4 GB heap memory, on Windows - up to 1 GB. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

@Nicolay, correct me if I'm wrong:

- the second map contains lists of people, ~900 people, as an entry. You mentioned each person is ~10KB, so each entry in the second map is ~9MB, even though you're saying it's 800KB in Json format. Can you please check the size of entries in the second map through Hazelcast. like: `client.getMap(map_name).getEntryView(key).getCost()`. This will give you entry memory cost in bytes.
- 500 concurrent req, if each entry is ~9MB, will require 4.5GB additional heap, which matches what you observed.

By looking numbers, everything seems fine, other that Json size being 800KB.

Can you check those numbers?

Comment: These persons in both maps are not the same for 100%. Both describe the person in real life but the last one in the list have less properties. I also tried to follow your suggestions and tried to evaluate client.getMap(map_name).getEntryView(key).getCost() but wasn't able to get an entry by a key inspite of the fact that I saw all the values in the map: [map with different persons](https://i.imgur.com/R5C4IW4.png), [null when try to retrieve a value by a key](https://i.imgur.com/7djTrZO.png)

Comment: Today I run stress tests on different PC (with a better processor, i7-6700, and Windows 10). And the tests surprisingly looked very good! The Heap almost didn't grow, the Committed Heap Memory size was just 670 MB. Then I continued with 1000 concurrent requests, after that with the 2000 and the heap was the same! [The stress test is here](https://streamable.com/wdak1).